# Return input from a jQuery dialog to the HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery

In my application I need to show a jQuery dialog to prompt a user for input, then return the user-supplied input to the page.

In the code below, I create the required HTML to get user input via the dialog, but I don't know how to return the value to my page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Dialog Box Witout Close Button</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<button id="dialog_trigger">open the dialog</button>
<div id="dialog" style="display:none;" title="Dialog Title"><iframe width="700" height="700" src="test.html"></iframe></div>
<script>
$( "#dialog_trigger" ).click(function() {
$( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});
$("#dialog").dialog({


    autoOpen: false,
    position: 'center' ,
    title: 'Sample Dialog',
    draggable: false,
    width : 500,
    height : 400, 
    resizable : true,

    buttons: {
            "Ok": function() {

               var firstname =  $('input[name=FirstName]').val();
var lastname =  $('input[name=LastName]').val();

localStorage.firstname = firstname;
localStorage.lastname = lastname;
              alert("Your name is: " + lastname);
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }}
});


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

//sample.html

```
 <html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function ExampleJS(){
    var jFirst = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    var jLast = document.getElementById("lname").value;



    var firstname = localStorage.firstname;
var lastname = localStorage.lastname;
if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined")
  {
      alert("yes");
  }
else
  {
      alert("no");
  }
  localStorage.lastname="Smith";
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Last name: "
+ localStorage.lastname;


   alert("Your name is: " + lastname);
 }
 </script>

</head>
<body>
    <FORM NAME="myform" onSubmit="JavaScript:ExampleJS()">

         First name: <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" /><br />
         Last name:  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" /><br />
        <input name="Submit"  type="submit" value="Update" />
    </FORM>
</body>
```

How can I get the value from `sample.html`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Using javaScript,

Assuming your two pages are on the same domain, you can use localStorage.

dialog.html

```
var firstname =  $('input[name=FirstName]').val();
var lastname =  $('input[name=LastName]').val();

localStorage.firstname = firstname;
localStorage.lastname = lastname;
```

Then back in the test.html page:

```
var firstname = localStorage.firstname;
var lastname = localStorage.lastname;
```

**Note 1**: I won't comment on security (other than to say of course don't do it like I've done it above!)

**Note 2**: localStorage is only about 92% supported: http://caniuse.com/namevalue-storage

## Is localstorage supported on your browser?

Try this code to detect,

```
if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined")
  {
      alert("yes");
  }
else
  {
      alert("no");
  }
```

Also then try,

```
localStorage.lastname="Smith";
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Last name: "
+ localStorage.lastname;
```

## If you can use PHP,

Use a form and a get or post method, to get the value on next page.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_get_post.htm

You may also use [cookies](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php).

Comment: but when i doing this i got undefined error in my page,it's possible to get element name from external html

Comment: @ Optimus Prime: ya that's my problem in my application have to show jquery dialog with another page after i need to retun value to previous page ,is't any way to do like this

Comment: still i cant get the value from the page can  u have any samples with jquery local storage more over i cant use php because my entire applicaion in jsp

Comment: i think i made some mistake while using local storage because when check with your code i got alert with "Yes" but i cant get value in second page,i have updated my code in question can you see

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be this; try this please.

dialog.html

```
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Dialog Box Witout Close Button</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
var firstname = localStorage.firstname;
var lastname = localStorage.lastname;

   alert("Your name is: " +firstname + " " + lastname);

 </script>
    </head>

<body>

You have been alerted on this page.

</body>
</html>
```

//sample.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function ExampleJS(){

var firstname =  document.getElementById("fname").value;
var lastname =  document.getElementById("lname").value;

localStorage.firstname = firstname;
localStorage.lastname = lastname;


   alert("Your name is: " + lastname);
   location.href="dialog.html";

   return false;
 }
 </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form name="myform" onSubmit="return ExampleJS();">

         First name: <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" /><br />
         Last name:  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" /><br />
        <input name="Submit"  type="submit" value="Update" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: in first html button event ,

Comment: Edited this again.Works totally for me @Mr.Cool . The problem was you did not have jQuery links in the html file and were using jquery functions.

Answer (score -1):

Use a `<form method="post">` in your sample.html for the inputs
Then, get it in the other page using the get method.
[w3schools form methods](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp)